# PIP3 command shows 'module' object is not callable

Tags: pip, python-3.4

Whenever I run pip3 commands, I get the following error:

```
$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 177, in main
    cmd_name, cmd_args = parseopts(initial_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 129, in parseopts
    parser = create_main_parser()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 122, in create_main_parser
    description = [''] + ['%-27s %s' % (i, j) for i, j in command_summaries]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 122, in <listcomp>
    description = [''] + ['%-27s %s' % (i, j) for i, j in command_summaries]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py", line 55, in get_summaries
    cmditems = _sort_commands(commands, commands_order)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py", line 88, in _sort_commands
    return sorted(list(cmddict.items()), key=keyfn)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable


$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.6
```

However, pip commands work on python 2.7.13. Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems like a problem with `pip` in Python 3.4: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34725282/7976758. Try to upgrade Python for the latest Python 3.4 or at least upgrade `pip`.

Comment: Updated python3 to version 3.4.6-25.7.1 and python3-pip to 1.5-1.74 (latest I can) but still the same issue.

Comment: Ttry to upgrade with [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: that didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall pip
```